# HTML not updating when running my Javascript twitch bot

Tags: javascript, html, twitch

```js
const tmi = require('tmi.js');

// Define configuration options
var x = "asdfasdf"
const opts = {
  identity: {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
  },
  channels: [
    "rabeya74"
  ]
};

// Create a client with our options
const client = new tmi.client(opts);

// Register our event handlers (defined below)
client.on('message', onMessageHandler);
client.on('connected', onConnectedHandler);

// Connect to Twitch:
client.connect();

// Called every time a message comes in
function onMessageHandler(target, context, msg, self) {
  if (self) {
    return;
  } // Ignore messages from the bot

  // Remove whitespace from chat message
  const commandName = msg.trim();

  // If the command is known, let's execute it
  if (commandName === '!dice') {
    const num = rollDice();
    client.say(target, `You rolled a ${num}`);
    document.body.innerHTML = x;
    console.log(`* Executed ${commandName} command`);
    document.body.innerHTML = `You rolled a ${num}`;
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "hello";
    }
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "hello";
  } else {
    console.log(`* Unknown command ${commandName}`);
  }
}
// Function called when the "dice" command is issued
function rollDice() {
  const sides = 6;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * sides) + 1;
}
// Called every time the bot connects to Twitch chat
function onConnectedHandler(addr, port) {
  console.log(`* Connected to ${addr}:${port}`);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="bot.js"></script>
  <div id="display"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to make a small twitch javascript app that updates the HTML file when I roll a dice. I tried every version of the document.body.innerHTML file but it simply does not want to update. Is it because it's in a function? It seems to just not show anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `require()` in the browser. This code produces an error because `require` is undefined. Try adding a `<script src="tmi.js"></script>` in your `<head>` element.

Comment: I just tried it but no difference? Nothing seems to pop up

Comment: @ZarifRahman Make sure to remove the `require` line from the other script.

Comment: I did const tmi = 'tmi.js' and also tried removing tmi as a whole as well but that doesn't really make sense. Both of them give me errors. TMI is a script from twitch which is not really in the workspace.